# MongoDb c# Driver bulk update with pull

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following code which was written via old legacy c# mongodb driver :

```
 var bulk = dbCollection.InitializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                    bulk.Find(Query.EQ("_id", profile.ID)).
                      Update(
                          Update.Pull("p2l",
                                Query.And(
                                    Query.In("listId", new BsonArray(SourceMailLists))
                                ))
                      );
            }
            bulk.Execute();
```

I want to rewrite it with `dbCollection.UpdateManyAsync` but how can i implement a `Pull` condition where `listid` from `p2l` collection should be in list `SourceMailLists`, also, i want to make it with typed `Builder` ?